# Animate paint stroke width on Android

Tags: android, animation, view

I'm trying to animate the drawing of an ellipses in a custom view.
The aim is to simulate the ellipses being drawn point by point with the stroke width getting thinner.

I'm trying by using two ValueAnimator's, one acting on the sweep angle and the other one on the stroke width.

Animating the drawing of the ellipses itself works fine, but I can't work out how to achieve the effect of the stroke width getting thinner.
The main difficulty I think is that every time I invalidate the view, the Rect within which the ellipses is drawn gets redrawn and therefore only the latest stroke width is visible as the ellipses gets completely redrawn.

Any suggestion is very welcomed, thank you.

Comment: Could you put an example of the code you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to invalidate view *every time when stroke width is changed* since canvas content has to be redrawn using a paint with different thickness.

So you should add UpadateListener (that one is used in Xamarin C#, not sure about Java syntax) and each time change stroke-width and call Invalidate() function.

This solution is far away from optimized one, but I could not find another one.

Any suggestion would help me as well.